# SQL Table with parent and child nodes (navigation table)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I have a single table with both parent and child nodes, and each has an order number in it.

I am trying to write a single query to output them in order, its for a navigation list with categories and sub-categories.

I could manage it in code rather than in the SQL query but it would involve calling a query from within a query loop - which I want to avoid.

Table:

```
DBID | Title | ParentID | OrderNum
 1      aaa       0          1
 2      bbb       0          2
 3      ccc       1          1
 4      ddd       1          2
 5      eee       2          1
```

and I want to get a result set like:

```
DBID | Title | ParentID | OrderNum
 1      aaa       0          1      <<< main 
 3      ccc       1          1      <<< child
 4      ddd       1          2      <<< 2nd child
 2      bbb       0          2      <<< main 
 5      eee       2          1      <<< child
```

I have been looking at using a recursive SQL select or Common Table Expressions (CTE) but have not been able to figure it out yet.

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

(Using SQL Server 2005 / ASP.Net C#)

Edit:
I should clarify that I only need it to go to 2 levels - i.e. parent and child, so it does not need to re-curse indefinitely, so I assume the answer is much simpler than I have been looking at.

Comment: Your results don't match your input data for OrderNum of DBID 2 (bbb). Is this intentional?

Comment: Ed you are correct thanks the orderNum was wrong for bbb changed it to 2

Comment: Added an explanation to my answer - let me know if it's not clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is recursion necessary? This appears to give the correct result:

```
declare @t table 
(DBID           int
,Title          varchar(10)
,ParentID       int
,OrderNum       int
)

insert @t
      select 1,'aaa',0,1
union select 2,'bbb',0,2
union select 3,'ccc',1,1
union select 4,'ddd',1,2
union select 5,'eee',2,1

select * 
from @t
order by ISNULL(NULLIF(ParentID,0),DBID)
        ,ParentID
        ,OrderNum
        ,DBID
```

**EDIT**

An explanation:

Since the input rows correspond 1:1 with the output rows and it's only the row order which changes, this must be an ordering problem. The solution is to identify the parent-child group to which each row belongs, and sort by that first, then all the other values.

The only difficult part of doing this is that parent rows (with `ParentID` = 0) gets its group membership implicitly from its `DBID`, whilst all the other rows get it from `ParentID`.

The first `WHERE` condition (`ISNULL(NULLIF(ParentID,0),DBID)`) handles this. It could also be written as

```
CASE WHEN ParentID = 0
     THEN DBID
     ELSE ParentID
END
```

I used `NULLIF...ISNULL` since it's more succinct, but if the sorting conditions were more complex I would have used `CASE...WHEN`.

Comment: That's the one. Thanks, could you give me a brief explanation? I really need to improve my SQL knowledge. Seems I presumed it was more complex a problem than it really was.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of years ago, I found the easiest way to do this (after hunting around) was to add "depth" and "path" columns to the table:

```
DBID | Title | ParentID | OrderNum | Path  | Depth
 0      Root     null        1       /         0
 1      aaa       0          1       /1/       1
 2      bbb       0          2       /2/       1
 3      ccc       1          1       /1/3/     2
 4      ddd       1          2       /1/4/     2
 5      eee       2          1       /2/5/     2
```

I then have a pair of triggers on the table to automatically update these on insert and update:

**Insert Trigger**

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[SiteMap_InsertTrigger] 
  ON  [dbo].[SiteMap] 
  AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
  -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
  -- interfering with SELECT statements.
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  UPDATE child
    -- set the depth of this "child" to be the
    -- depth of the parent, plus one.
    SET Depth = ISNULL(parent.depth + 1, 0),
      -- the lineage is simply the lineage of the parent,
      -- plus the child's ID (and appropriate '/' characters
      Path = ISNULL(parent.Path, '/') + LTrim(child.DBID) + '/'

    -- we can't update the "inserted" table directly,
    -- so we find the corresponding child in the
    -- "real" table
    FROM SiteMap child INNER JOIN inserted i ON i.Id = child.DBID
      -- now, we attempt to find the parent of this
      -- "child" - but it might not exist, so these
      -- values may well be NULL
      LEFT OUTER JOIN SiteMap parent ON child.ParentId = parent.DBID
END
```

**Update Trigger**

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[SiteMap_UpdateTrigger] 
  ON  [dbo].[SiteMap] 
  AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
  -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
  -- interfering with SELECT statements.
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  -- if we've modified the parentId, then we
  -- need to do some calculations
  IF UPDATE (ParentId)
  BEGIN
    UPDATE child
      /*
      to calculate the correct depth of a node, remember that
        - old.depth is the depth of its old parent
        - child.depth is the original depth of the node
          we're looking at before a parent node moved.
          note that this is not necessarily old.depth + 1,
          as we are looking at all depths below the modified
          node
      The depth of the node relative to the old parent is
      (child.depth - old.depth), then we simply add this to the
      depth of the new parent, plus one.
      */
      SET Depth = child.Depth - old.Depth + ISNULL(parent.Depth + 1,0),
        Path = ISNULL(parent.Path,'/') + LTrim(old.DBID) + '/' +
        right(child.Path, len(child.Path) - len(old.Path))
        -- if the parentId has been changed for some row
        -- in the "inserted" table, we need to update the
        -- fields in all children of that node, and the
        -- node itself                 
      FROM SiteMap child
      INNER JOIN inserted old ON child.Path LIKE old.Path + '%'
        -- as with the insert trigger, attempt to find the parent
        -- of the updated row
      LEFT OUTER JOIN SiteMap parent ON old.ParentId=parent.DBID
  END;
END;
```

Which then makes it a lot easier to jump into a particular category and pull out all the children and sub-children very quickly by searching across Path or depth.

Interestingly, I've just found that SQL Server 2008 includes a new type: [HierarchyId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290.aspx) which basically rolls the Path column up into a compact type.

Comment: Hi thanks for the input. I have clarified the question as I only really need it to work to 2 levels deep for now.

Also I need to pull the whole data set out in one go - rather than passing in a parent and pulling out its child elements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can achieve this by using either recursive sql or cte.

I think this solution will help you to solve this hierarchical table select.

[http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETPlayground/archive/2007/12/28/118017.aspx](https://web.archive.org/web/20150511142500/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/dotNETPlayground/archive/2007/12/28/118017.aspx)

Comment: also check this similar post 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088928/hierarchical-database-select-insert-statement-sql-server

Comment: Hi, its close but only gives me a result per main category ID, i.e. I have to pass in the parents ID. Is there any way I can recurse this to get them all in one go?

Comment: This also is close but it depends on pulling out all the levels for a given parent. I want to pull out the whole list, please note I have clarified the question so that I only need 2 levels deep - which should make this a simpler query to resolve I hope. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [nested-set model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model). This allows whole trees to be fetched in one SQL statement. The disadvantage is that write operations become more complex.

Alternatively you could write a recursive stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

This a recursive approach. using CTE.

```
with cte
as
(
select *, 1 as [level], [DBID] as [father]
from @t
where parentID=0
union all
select t.*, [level]+1, cte.[father]
from @t t
inner join cte on cte.DBID=t.parentID
)
select  [DBID],Title, ParentID,  OrderNum  
from cte
order by [father], [level],  OrderNum
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is spot on. Here it is in linq as well:

```
var orderedItems = from item in dataContext.items
                   orderby (item.ParentID == 0 ? item.DBID : item.ParentID),
                       item.ParentID , item.OrderNum, item.DBID
                   select item;
```